# Open new prompts to run binaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I want my python script to run several other executables (all of which run on the windows cmd).

I'm currently using

```
subprocess.Popen(content)
```

But this will open all the executables on the same terminal running the script, and I need every executable to run on it's own terminal.

My first idea was

```
subprocess.Popen("cmd /C " + content)
```

But that also uses only a single terminal.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
os.system("start " + content)
```

did the trick

and it seems like

```
os.startfile(content)
```

would also work